# set upload folder in dataobject to the title of the related page - Silverstripe 3.1

Tags: php, silverstripe

hi i've got a gallery page. this **gallery page** has a **gallery image object** with an has_many relation.

```
    private static $has_many = array(
    'GalleryImages' => 'GalleryObject'
);
```

my **gallery object** has an image upload field. I want to set the upload folder to the title of the **gallery page**

i tried this with no result

```
$visual->setFolderName('Galerie/'.$this->Gallery()->Title);
```

and this (what i would prefer)

```
    public function getGalleryTitle() {
    $galleryTitle = $this->Gallery()->Title->First();
    $uploadFolder = str_replace(' ', '-', $this->$galleryTitle);
    return $uploadFolder;
}

$visual->setFolderName('Galerie/'.$this->$uploadFolder);
```

the second returns and error (undefined variable uploadFolder ?!) and my upload folder is now set to "Galerie/DataList"

can someone tell me how to convert the output of $uploadFolder so that i get back the title?

**EDIT:**

GalleryHolder: http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/5267dea3579a6

GalleryPage: http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/5267dee4c9752

GalleryObject: http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/5267df0af1a65

Comment: can you post the classes with your code, it gets quite confusing when looking at 'GalleryPage', 'GalleryImages' & 'Gallery()', not sure where 'Gallery()' comes from. If you can post your code with the class and the relation definition, we'll be able to give you the right code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you where almost there..

Here is your edited `getGalleryTitle()` function.

It is basically checking if the `GalleryObject` has a parent Gallery via `$this->GalleryID`. Since it is a `has_one` relation the column will be named `GalleryID`.

Then we get the Gallery object with `$this->Gallery()` and get it's title with `$gallery->Title`.

I've also replaced your `str_replace` with SilverStripe's `URLSegmentFilter` class. Which will removed spaces and other special characters non welcome in URL, a better solution.

```
  public function getGalleryTitle()
  {       
      if ( $this->GalleryID )
      {
        $gallery = $this->Gallery();
        $filter = new URLSegmentFilter();
        return $filter->filter( $gallery->Title );
      }
      else{
        return 'default';
      }

  }
```

Then in the `getCMSFields()` function, when creating your `UploadField` we just call the `getGalleryTitle()` function that returns the string for the folder name.

```
  $visual = new UploadField('Visual', _t('Dict.IMAGE', 'Image'));
  $visual->setFolderName('Galerie/'.$this->getGalleryTitle());
```

A few notes..

`$this` references the current Object instance, so you can't use `$this->$galleryTitle` to access a variable you just created in your function, `$galleryTitle` by itself is enough.

You were calling `$this->$uploadFolder` in `setFolderName`, this doesn't work for the same reason, and also, using `$uploadFolder` by itself wouldn't work since this variable was created in the scope of another function. So we just call the function we defined on our Object with `$this->getGalleryTitle()` since it returns the value we want.

This should work fine, but keep in mind that if the Title of the Gallery changes at some point, the folder name will change too. So you might end up with images uploaded in many different folders for the same gallery... I personally wouldn't advise it, unless you implement some kind of "Title locking system" or some way to keep the "correct" or first "valid/acceptable" Gallery title in a separate object property that can't be edited and use this in the folder name.

I usually only use the `ID` in those case ($gallery->ID), as this will not change.

**edit**

Another version of `getGalleryTitle()` that should work even if the `GalleryObject` isn't saved yet.

```
  public function getGalleryTitle()
  {       
        $parentID = Session::get('CMSMain')['currentPage'];

      if ( $parentID )
      {
        $gallery = Page::get()->byID( $parentID );
        $filter = new URLSegmentFilter();
        return $filter->filter( $gallery->Title );
      }
      else{
        return 'default';
      }
  }
```

Comment: ah, this explains why it doesn't work. Thank you for this explanation. Your right, using the gallery title isn't so smart. I'll use the ID instead.
But the function always returns default, and if i use it without the if statement, nothing is returned (0 for each gallery if i use id). Somewhere is a mistake, but i can't spot it out.

Comment: it will return default if the GalleryObject isn't added to a GalleryPage (GalleryID = 0). How do you create your GalleryObjects? Via ModelAdmin? Or a GridFieldRealtionEditor?

Comment: with a normal gridfield `new GridField('GalleryImages', _t('Dict.GALLERY_IMAGES', 'Gallery Images'), $this->GalleryImages(), CreateSortableGrid::create());` in my getCMSFields function on the GallyerPage. If you want have a look at the attached links in my question. there you can see the whole code

Comment: Works fine when I test it. Although, when you create a new GalleryObject, **before saving**, the GalleryObject doesn't exist so it doesn't have a `GalleryID` so the folder is default. You can wrap your UploadField in a `if ($this->ID)` statement so images can be uploaded only if the GalleryObject is saved and has a GalleryID.

Comment: You'r right. I need to save it first. But is there another way to set the upload folder to The GalleryPage ID before saving it?

Comment: you should be able to use the session `Session::get('CMSMain')['currentPage']`, see updated answer.

Comment: This works! :) But is it normal that I get an Syntax error in my editor. The error is shown here: `n')['c`

Comment: well, it could be written better: `$session = Session::get('CMSMain')`, then check if this exist `if ($session)` then get the value from the array `$parentID = $session['currentPage']`

Comment: great :) if you want to update your answer, here's the complete code. `public function getGalleryID() {       
  $session = Session::get('CMSMain');
  if ($session) {
   $parentID = $session['currentPage'];
         $gallery = Page::get()->byID( $parentID );
         $filter = new URLSegmentFilter();
         return $filter->filter( $gallery->ID );
       }
  else {
         return 'default';
  }
 }`

Answer (score 0):

First, I check to see whether we're on the `CMSSettingsPage` or in a `ModelAdmin` page (Should you be using them). You want to get all the information about which class the controller is managing as it's data record. (If you have firebug, `FB($this)` in `getCMSFields()` on the related `DataObject` (DO) will show you the page managed under `DataRecord`)

`Controller::curr()->currentPage()` will get you the current page the DO is being managed on, and `->URLSegment` will get the page url name, though you could use `Title` or `MenuTitle` also.

Here is an example which will set up a folder underneath *assets/Headers* to save images in. Running this on the `HomePage` (ie URL Segment 'home') will create and save objects into the folder */assets/Headers/home*.

```
if (Controller::curr()->class == 'CMSSettingsController' || Controller::curr() instanceof Modeladmin) {
    $uploadField->setFolderName('Headers');
}
else
{
    $uploadField->setFolderName('Headers/' . Controller::curr()->currentPage()->URLSegment);
}
```